# GIS Master/Certificate Program Rankings

Tags: education

I am currently looking into obtaining additional formal education in the GIS field. I have looked into several university programs and contacted representative to learn more about the details and pricing. There seems to be a fairly large discrepancy in pricing and I am finding it hard to determine if the higher price is worth it. I have searched online for an independent ranking of accredited GIS programs but so far have only come up with http://www.justinholman.com/2016/01/21/2016-rankings-top-10-online-masters-programs-in-gis/. I am unsure as to the credibility of this site.

Is there any professional GIS organization that offers a ranking system for colleges offering GIS certificates or degrees?

If that is not available, then lists of performance statistics such as graduation rates and % of graduates employed in a related field would suffice. This would help me determine perceived value.

I am looking at online programs as relocation is not an option for me.